# Why my tar.gz file was truncated in the process of transfer by ssh2_scp_send function?

Tags: php, ssh

There is a file in my local pc.

```
ls -al /tmp/back.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11219553 Nov 29 23:13 /tmp/back.tar.gz
```

Let's upload the back.tar.gz with ssh2_scp_send into my remote vps.

```
<?php
    $vps_ip= 'xxxx';
    $port = 'yyyy';
    $user = 'root';
    $passwd = 'zzzz';
    $connection = ssh2_connect($vps_ip, $port);
    ssh2_auth_password($connection,$user,$passwd);
    ssh2_scp_send($connection,'/tmp/back.tar.gz','/home/back.tar.gz');
?>
```

Login into ssh with `ssh -p yyyy root@xxxx` to execute ls command in my vps.

```
ls  -al  /home/back.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11206656 Nov 29 10:10 /home/back.tar.gz
```

Where is the 12897 bytes left?

Now i upload the file /tmp/back.tar.gz  in my local pc into remote vps the second time,when the php program executed.
Login into ssh with `ssh -p yyyy root@xxxx` to execute ls command in my vps.

```
ls  -al  /home/back.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11219505 Nov 29 10:10 /home/back.tar.gz
```

I think that there is a bug in  ssh2_scp_send function ,it is unstable.
I have tested also with scp command for three times:

```
scp -P  $port root@$vps_ip:/home/back.tar.gz    /tmp
```

Login into ssh with `ssh -p yyyy root@xxxx` to execute ls command in my vps.

```
ls  -al  /home/back.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11219553 Nov 29 10:10 /home/back.tar.gz
```

It is my conclusion that some bug in ssh2_scp_send function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buffer works here.

```
ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit');
```

To write bytes in buffer before closing the connection.